# Обработка формы в React TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, form

имеется кнопка при нажатии на которую открывается модальное окно в котором форма из одного поля. Проблема в том что из-за не получается вытащить данные, хотя если модального окна не будет, все нормально выводиться в консоль, что может быть не так?

```
interface ISignInForm {
    login: string;
}

export const AddPost: React.FC = () => {
const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm<ISignInForm>();

const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<ISignInForm> = data => console.log(data);


const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
};

const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
};
return (
    <div>
        <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <Button variant="outlined" color="primary" onClick={handleClickOpen}>
            Open form dialog
        </Button>
            <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                <DialogContent>
                    <Controller
                        control={control}
                        name="login"
                        render={({ field }) => (
                        <TextField
                            onChange={(e) => field.onChange(e)}
                            autoFocus
                            margin="dense"
                            id="name"
                            label="Email Address"
                            type="email"
                            fullWidth
                        />
                        )}
                    />
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                        Cancel
                    </Button>
                    <Button type="submit" color="primary">
                        Ok
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </form>
    </div>
);
}
```

Comment: *Проблема в том что из-за не получается вытащить данные* - Тут явно вы что то не дописали... `render={({ field })` - кто такой field и чему он равен?

Comment: SwaD, Да, вы правы, не хватает value={field.value}, но теперь летит ошибка  A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled...

Comment: SwaD,Или может есть другой способ вытащить данные с формы? (Мало опыта в TS)

Comment: Что и где вы поправили? Что такое field? Внесите исправления в ваш вопрос. Сейчас не понятно, что и где может ругаться

Comment: SwaD, Пример брался с этого кода, я добавил лишь модальное окно
https://github.com/brian7346/react-hook-form/blob/main/src/pages/auth-page/auth-form/auth-form.tsx

Comment: Скорее всего, это [ответ на ваш вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1486652/%d0%94%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b2-previousinputvalue-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5/1486663#1486663)